# SQL count - first time

Tags: sql

I am learning SQL (bit by bit!) trying to perform a query on our database and adding in a count function to show the total orders that appear against a customers id by counting in a inner join query.

Somehow it is pooling all the data together onto one customer with the count function though.

Can someone please suggest where I am going wrong?

```
SELECT tbl_customers.*, tbl_stateprov.stprv_Name, tbl_custstate.CustSt_Destination, COUNT(order_id) as total
        FROM tbl_stateprov 
            INNER JOIN (tbl_customers 
                INNER JOIN (tbl_custstate
                INNER JOIN tbl_orders ON tbl_orders.order_CustomerID = tbl_custstate.CustSt_Cust_ID)
                ON tbl_customers.cst_ID = tbl_custstate.CustSt_Cust_ID) 
            ON tbl_stateprov.stprv_ID = tbl_custstate.CustSt_StPrv_ID
        WHERE tbl_custstate.CustSt_Destination='BillTo'
AND cst_LastName LIKE '#URL.Alpha#%'
```

Comment: I actually wouldn't have thought that would have worked as you normally require Group By when including Count in a query.

Comment: yep, you need GROUP BY on every column that you select when using COUNT

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but you only need brackets for subqueries, or to group sets of conditions.  For your query, you don't need any.

Comment: Yes *normally* parenthesis are optional and `group by` is required - but not always. It depends on which database you are using. For next time, be sure to include your db type in the question tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY` clause in this statement in order to get what you want.  You need to figure out what level you want to group it by in order to select which fields to add to the group by clause.  If you just wanted to see it on a per customer basis, and the customers table had an `id` field, it would look like this (at the very end of your sql):

```
GROUP BY tbl_customers.id
```

Now you can certainly group by more fields, it just depends how you want to slice the results.

Comment: Thankyou, such an obvious edit made a huge difference. It worked perfectly, really grateful :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your select statement you are using format like tableName.ColumnName but not for COUNT(order_id)

It should be COUNT(tableOrAlias.order_id)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As you are new to SQL it might also be worth considering the readability of your joins - the nested / bracketed joins you mentioned above are quite hard to read, and I would also personally alias your tables to make the query that bit more accessible:

```
SELECT 
tbl_customers.customer_id
,tbl_stateprov.stprv_Name
,tbl_custstate.CustSt_Destination
,COUNT(order_id) as total
FROM tbl_stateprov statep
INNER JOIN tbl_custstate state ON statep.stprv_ID = state.CustSt_StPrv_ID
INNER JOIN tbl_customers  customer ON customer.cst_ID = state.CustSt_Cust_ID 
INNER JOIN tbl_orders orders ON orders.order_CustomerID = state.CustSt_Cust_ID
WHERE tbl_custstate.CustSt_Destination='BillTo'
AND cst_LastName LIKE '#URL.Alpha#%'
GROUP BY
tbl_customers.customer_id
,tbl_stateprov.stprv_Name
,tbl_custstate.CustSt_Destination
--And any other columns you want to include the count for
```

Comment: If you give recommendations to format a query properly, you should at least indent your statement to make it readable.